How do I set up PyTorch model (e.g. GFPGAN) for tracing?
I'm having trouble setting up my GFPGAN PyTorch model for tracing, so that I can convert it to a CoreML model. My understanding is I also need to define a class that inherits from Torch.nn.Module, which defines the structure of the GPFGAN model, and the .pth file contains the weights. But I have no idea where to find the information to define the class that inherits from Torch.nn.Module. Am I missing something?
I found some classes that inherit from Torch.nn.Module in the GFPGAN python library, but they all result in errors when trying to load the state dict into it.
Here's my code:
import torch
from gfpgan.archs import gfpganv1_clean_arch

model_path = 'GFPGANv1.4.pth'
traceable_model = gfpganv1_clean_arch.GFPGANv1Clean(out_size=512)
traceable_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path)) # Error occurs here.
traceable_model.eval()
trace = torch.jit.trace(traceable_model, input_batch)

How am I supposed to load the GFPGANv1.4 model for tracing?
